# How to properly error-catch Android camera activity when using the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, error-handling, android-camera

In Android, taking a picture can be done with this basic setup as seen [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).

```
protected void dispatchTakePictureIntent(){
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

        ...
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile)); 
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //do stuff with the output file
    }
}
```

However, [third-party camera apps are unpredictable and cannot be guaranteed to play nice](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html).

What is the correct way to validate the output / catch any errors? Should I be wrapping `startActivityForResult` inside of a try/catch block? What are the various types of exceptions I should be trying to catch and what should I do with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be wrapping startActivityForResult inside of a try/catch block?

Yes, though this has nothing to do with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` specifically. The user may not have access to a camera app (e.g., the user is running under a restricted profile on a shared device). Any time you call `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()` with an implicit `Intent`, you need to deal with the possibility that there is no available app.

> What are the various types of exceptions I should be trying to catch and what should I do with them?

In the answer that you linked to, I was pointing out crashes *in the camera app*. You cannot catch those, as that is not your app.

Beyond `ActivityNotFoundException`, you also need to think about Android 6.0 runtime permissions, as you need the `CAMERA` permission to start an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity. Usually, though, this will not involve an exception handler.

The other validations would be not based on exceptions, but based on flawed results:

- If you supplied `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, is there any content at the `Uri` you specified? In theory, if the user did not cancel out of the camera app, there will be, but that is not guaranteed, due to camera app bugs.
- If there is is content, is it plausibly an image file? For example, you might use `BitmapFactory` with `inJustDecodeBounds` to see if the image really is an image.
- If there is no content, did you happen to get a `Uri` back in the result `Intent` in `onActivityResult()`? The buggy camera app might have stored the image where it wanted to and supplied the `Uri` to it, even though this is way out of spec for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.
- If there is no content, and there is no `Uri`, does `getExtras("data")` return a non-`null` value? In that case, you at least got a thumbnail and can save it yourself, even though the image quality may suck.

Comment: Regarding the possible `Uri back in the result Intent`, I am not familiar with `Uri` usage yet but based on my Googling just now, are you saying to check if something like `Uri myUri = Uri.parse(data.getExtras().getString(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT));` gives a `Uri` containing a `file:` type?

Comment: @KaliMa: No, I mean if `getData()` on the `Intent` handed to `onActivityResult()` returns the `Uri`. I suppose it's not out of the question that a camera app could *send* you an `Intent` with an `EXTRA_OUTPUT` extra via `onActivityResult()`, but I have not heard of that scenario. I have heard of camera apps sending the `Uri` back as the `Uri` of the `Intent` itself.

Comment: But if I have specified `takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile)); ` don't I already know where the resulting picture file will be in `onActivityResult()`? Or do some apps ignore that completely and put it wherever they want?

Comment: @KaliMa: "don't I already know where the resulting picture file will be" -- in theory, yes. "Or do some apps ignore that completely and put it wherever they want?" -- yes, because some `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` implementations have bugs.